# I can't find my bin folder. Where is it located?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The other day I was trying to download something for Minecraft and it involved my bin folder. So I was looking for it and couldn't find it. I then thought that I might have accidentally deleted it, but didn't find it in the trash. I have no idea how to get the bin folder back with all the Minecraft binary files in them.

Answer (score 13):

#### Pre 1.6 (Old Launcher)

If you deleted your `bin` directory it will be recreated when you launch the Minecraft client.

If the client starts up, your `bin` directory is almost certainly at:

- Windows: `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft` or `%AppData%\.minecraft`
- Linux: `~/.minecraft`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`

#### Post 1.6.1 (New Launcher)

The new launcher does not create a `bin` directory. Instead, there is one folder for every installed different version of the game, located in the folder `versions` in your Minecraft directory (see above). For example `1.7.10`, or `14w30c`. Note that multiple profiles can use the same version and there will only be one folder.

Comment: @Sonos If my answer helped, mark it as accepted with the tick mark to the left. It'll earn you reputation!

Comment: For completeness: on linux it's located at `~/.minecraft`

Comment: For completeness: on Mac it's located at `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`

Comment: On Windows you can actually type `%AppData%\.minecraft` on Explorer's address bar.

Comment: And what to do if your bin-folder isn't recreated? Legal account, by the way, but reinstalling minecraft fort the 1000 time, no bin folder is created... My son is really sad...

Comment: @Paula Run the launcher; it will redownload the files. Otherwise, download them manually. Thecurrent version doesn't create a bin folder anymore. Look in versions > 1.6.2