# I can't find my Bin file on minecraft 1.6.2!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I am currently trying to make my own texture pack for Minecraft, I keep looking for the BIN file on the folders but I can't find anything. I want to make my own texture pack but I can't seem to find it, or I can't even see any tutorials about it. 
First of all: What folder are the textures anyway? 
And also, how can I make my own texture pack?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/how-to-install-mods-for-the-new-minecraft-launcher-1-6-1/122250#122250

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120679/lost-my-bin-folder-and-my-minecraft-binary-files-what-do-i-do

Comment: Hm, that second one needs updating, actually. Everything changed a lot in 1.6.

Comment: @Billy Ya quite a few things did change. Not sure why they changed the name of of the texture pack folder to resourcepack (or resource pack). It's their choice ultimately, but some of the changes feel unneeded.

Comment: @Scootaloo Because it's no longer just textures—now it's textures, sounds, music, etc., anything that is in the assets folder in the jar.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like at one point or another they moved a few things around. For Linux it should be in:

> ~/.minecraft

From there go into the folder labeled **1.6.2**, and do what you need to with the jar.

Textures packs go into:

> ~/.minecraft/resourcepacks

As for making your own texture pack I suggest you look at [the one on the Minecaft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Custom_Texture_Packs). There is even [a little section](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Custom_Texture_Packs#Ubuntu.2FGNOME) at the bottom that shows you how to package it (should work for most Linux Distributions).

Comment: 1.6 no longer uses the texturepacks folder; it's resourcepacks now.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I forgot about that, thanks. Edited.